# iGraph Cairo error, unable to import iGraph even though I installed Cairo

Tags: igraph, macports, cairo, pycairo

Before I installed Cairo, iGraph was working completely fine. After, the installation, iGraph is no longer working.

The error I get is this:

> raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover
>   OSError: no library called "cairo" was found
>   no library called "libcairo-2" was found
>   cannot load library 'libcairo.so': dlopen(libcairo.so, 2): image not found
>   cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': dlopen(libcairo.2.dylib, 2): image not found
>   cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': dlopen(libcairo-2.dll, 2): image not found

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It seems that the underlying C library of `cairo` was not installed, see https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html. But it is difficult to judge without more information. What OS are you on, how did you install the Python `cairo` bindings? Did you install `pycairo` or `cairocffi`?